# No timing info for RING_BUFFER_CONNECTIVITY in dm_os_ring_buffers

Tags: sql-server, networking

I'm attempting to diagnose what I believe is a networking issue.  There have been a lot of connection issues with a certain SQL Server machine, but I don't think the problem is on the database side, and I'd like to try and prove it.

I'm using sys.dm_os_ring_buffers and looking at the RING_BUFFER_CONNECTIVITY type in order to try and get to the bottom of this.  I'm seeing a ton of "LoginTimers" errors, where the SniConsumerError = 17830, but all of the columns that I'd really like to see - NetworkWritesInMS, NetworkReadsInMS, SspiProcessingInMS - are all NULL.

Does anyone know why there would be no information captured for those columns?  I think that information would be extremely helpful to me for this issue.  Is there anything I can do to get data captured there?

Right now, the error message just reads "**Network error code 0x%x occurred while establishing a connection; the connection has been closed. This may have been caused by client or server login timeout expiration. Time spent during login: total %d ms, enqueued %d ms, network writes %d ms, network reads %d ms, establishing SSL %d ms, network reads during SSL %d ms, network writes during SSL %d ms, secure calls during SSL %d ms, enqueued during SSL %d ms, negotiating SSPI %d ms, network reads during SSPI %d ms, network writes during SSPI %d ms, secure calls during SSPI %d ms, enqueued during SSPI %d ms, validating login %d ms, including user-defined login processing %d ms.%.*ls**"

I'm hoping to proceed with more info.  Many thanks in advance for anyone who can help!

Comment: I'm troubleshooting the same issue now. My current theory is that somehow two processes are taking the same SPID at the same time, but i'm going to have to work with our SharePoint admin to check the SharePoint side. I'm seeing this on a few servers, but for now looking at the server that hosts SharePoint databases.